# How to get the version history of a list using Client Object Model Sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, history

I want to access the list item history details since I have some multiline fields which are all enabled with append data mode. Also, I want to see if any date is modified after creation of that item and etc. How can I do it through Sharepoint 2010 Client Object Model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is demonstrated here:

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/16/programmatically-get-document-version-history-using-client-object-model-sharepoint-2010/